# How to display just one menu in a dynamic menu

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I hava a dynamic menu using VueJs and Laravel. It works fine.
But when I display one of them, all options are displayed.
The menu starts in foreach loop to check menu and assigned options.
Is there any way to restrict this? 
My code is the next:
File sidebar.blade.php

```
<div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li @click="menu=0" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i>  Escritorio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-title">
                        Menú de opciones
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        @foreach($menus as $menu)
                            <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="{{ $menu->icono_menu }}"></i>{{ $menu->nombre }}</a>
                            @foreach($permisos as $permiso)
                                @if($menu->id==$permiso->idmenu)
                                     <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                                        <li @click="menu={{ $permiso->codigo }}" class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="{{ $permiso->icono_opcion }}"></i> {{ $permiso->nombre }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </li>
                    <li @click="menu=27" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-book-open"></i> Ayuda <span class="badge badge-danger">PDF</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li @click="menu=28" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-info"></i> Acerca de...<span class="badge badge-info">IT</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Share `$permisos` and `$menus` value

Comment: I found the solution, it was to move the tag <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown"></li> inside the first foreach.